# How would I render data from a Django model with a React frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, ajax, frontend

I'm currently working on a personal portfolio website using Django for the backend and database, and React for all the frontend stuff.

In this program, I have various fields that I would like to update every once in a while; I have Django tables for my education history, my work experiences, my skills, and a table to hold portfolio entries. I'd like to display this information on my React frontend, where I could display a page containing cards with all the portfolio projects I've created, and a page where my work experience, skills, and education history is all displayed.

Using plain Django, I would have simply selected the items from the table in views.py and passed it to the context, rendering the items as needed. With React, I don't know how I would handle such a request.

The way my code currently works, in the React components, I declare objects with the required fields such as

```
const myExperiences = [{
        name: "Company name",
        title: "job title",
        description: "job description",
        startDate: "start", 
        endDate: "end",
        location: "city, country",
    }]
```

and I display them by using the map function to put them in the desired format.

This is not ideal as it'd require me to change my source code any time I'd like to add more entries, where I would rather do it from Django admin console.

My other idea was to fetch the data from a Django API, but that seems inefficient, and having to fetch information from 3 different tables every time the page feels like it'd be slow for the user for no reason.

What is the right course of action here? What would you guys suggest?

Comment: Don't overthink performance as Django is pretty powerful when it comes to build smart queries. Create a Django Rest API, make a request to one of your endpoints on the React client side and return the queryset as json within the APIs view. Then you can map the object in React etc. etc.

Comment: @JSRB. Could you provide a sample code. I'm in the same situation right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested please find below a basic common approach with a React / Django setup:

1. Make an (async) API request in React to your Django endpoint/view (in this case I'm using standard fetch API)
2. Map the returned JSON to create DOM elements for rendering

```
import PayrollRuns from "./PayrollRuns";
import PayrollDetails from "./PayrollDetails";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import moment from "moment";


const PayrollWrapper = () => {

    // Set State for Payroll data
    const [payrollRuns, setPayrollRuns] = useState([])

    // Fetch data --> 1.)
    useEffect(() => {

        // Fetch the Payroll Data related to the logged in User
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lastpayrollruns/`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setPayrollRuns(data)
          });
    }, []);

    // --> 2.)
    const runItems = props.payrollRuns.map((run) =>
        <div key={run.id} className="flex justify-between p-2 text-lg text-base">
            <div>
                {moment(run.month.period).format('YYYY MMMM')}:
                Paid {run.payroll_run_items.length} talents
            </div>

            <div>
                {run.payroll_run_items.reduce((acc, value) => {
                  return parseFloat(value.amount.toFixed(2)) + acc; // Add 'value.amount' to 'acc'
                }, 0)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div className="runs-wrapper bg-white rounded-xl h-full w-48 shadow-sx-shadow p-4 flex flex-col">
            <h1 className="border-b-2 pb-4">Payroll Runs</h1>
            <div className="grow overflow-auto p-4">{runItems}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PayrollWrapper
```

Django API endpoint/view for the given example:

```
class PayrollRun(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve payroll runs including line items for a company
    """
    def get(self, request):
        company = Company.objects.get(userprofile__user=request.user)
        payroll_runs = Payroll.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('-month')
        serializer = PayrollSerializer(payroll_runs, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note:

One key concept of this setup is to provide the authentication header (token) for the API request as you will want to access the Django `authenticated user (request.user)` object in your views to make the database queries according to the user on client side.